# Office 365 API Tool - ActiveDirectory DirectoryObjects don't include Manager or DirectReports

Tags: api, office365

I'm using the new Office365 API Tool and the ActiveDirectoryAPISample code method GetUsers.  The users that are returned have their Manager and DirectReports properties set to null.  Is there something I need to do in order to retrieve the manager/direct report information?